# grep recursion - inconsistencies

Tags: linux, unix, recursion, grep

I'm looking for a particular string (mainly in .c files) recursively from the root directory.

When I use this, I get a list back almost immediately.

```
grep -rl "F_capture" .
```

However, if I try to speed things up by just searching .c files:

```
grep -r --include=*.c "F_capture" .
```

I end up with a slew of recursive directory warnings like this:

```
grep: warning: ./sys/block/fd0/device/bus/drivers/i8042/i8042/serio1/input:event1/subsystem/event3/device/bus/drivers/pcnet32/0000:00:03.0/subsystem: recursive directory loop
```

When I tried suppressing the warnings using the -s parameter, I don't get the warnings but I don't get anything back either - seems like it's going off into never never land.

```
grep -rsl --include="*.c" "F_capture" .
```

So I guess my question is, why does the first grep I used return something immediately and the other types where I'm targeting a specific type of file seem to hang up. I would think the targeted search would be faster.

Comment: It looks like a BUG. The `-r` following symbolic links only if they are on the command line. Seems, the `--include` breaks this, and the grep trying following symbolic links.

Comment: Do you get the same errors when you try `--include=*.c` (as in your second quoted line above) and `--include="*.c"` (as in your fourth quoted line above)?  If not, what do you get from `shopt | grep glob` (assuming you're using bash)?

Comment: dg99 - yes, if I take out the -s switch, I get the same errors if I use "*.c" or *.c. When I type shopt | grep glob I get a list of "globs" - all are off.

Comment: why not using find -type f -name "*.c" -exec grep -l "F_capture" {} \;

Comment: Which version of grep do you have? "-r" semantic changed in grep 2.12.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -print|xargs grep -l "F_capture"
```

Comment: Change `-print` to `-print0` and change `xargs` to `xargs -0` and this code will support spaces: `find . -type f -name "*.c" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "F_capture"`.  This could also use some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
grep "F_capture" `find -type f -name "*.c"`
```